# Starting out with SoapUI and CouchDB

Tags: json, rest, couchdb, soapui

Hi just a quick question. I'm using SoapUI and CouchDB, and I created a POST method in soapui to post a simple JSON name value pair. But when I click submit I get an SSLException:Unrecognized SSL Message, plaintext connection? I also get back some xml

```
<data contentType="null" contentLength="0"><![CDATA[]]></data>
```

Im finding the documentation a little hard to follow so if anyone could point me the right way here it would be great.

Comment: So the CouchDB server is hosted with under HTTPS? Can you provide more details? What is the full request that you send to CouchDB and the full response that you get from it.

Comment: Its hosted under Futon, which the tutorial I was following recommended. Thats HTTP though, not HTTPS. I created a POST method in soapui, then filled a application/json form with {"name":"example"}. I did this with curl on the command line and it worked fine.

Comment: are you sure your're calling the right url under soapui? is there any SSL checkbox checked? Again, please provide more details if you really need others to help.

Comment: I took a second look and saw that I was calling to HTTPS, not HTTP. when I fixed that the request went through! Think I missed it from staring at the bloody thing for too long. Thanks! :D